# How to terminate a job dispatcher in back ground in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, process

I have a job dispatcher bash shell script containing below codes:

```
for (( i=0; i<$toBeDoneNum; i=i+1 ))
do
    while true
    do
            processNum=`ps aux | grep Checking | wc -l`
            if [ $processNum -lt $maxProcessNum ]; then
                break
            fi
            echo "Too many processes: Max process is $maxProcessNum."
            sleep $sleepSec
    done
    java -classpath ".:./conf:./lib/*" odx.comm.cwv.main.Checking $i
done
```

I run the script like this to be in the background:

```
./dispatcher.sh &
```

I want to terminate this dispatcher process with kill -9. But I didn't record the pid of the dispatcher process at the first time. Instead I used jobs to show all the process but it shows nothing. Even this fg cannot bring the process to foreground.

```
fg
bash: fg: current: no such job
```

But I think this dispatcher process is still running because it still continues to assign java program to run. How should I terminate this job dispatcher bash shell script process?

Edit: I used jobs, jobs -l, jobs -r and jobs -s. Nothing showed.

Comment: There's a Linux Q&A site too, it might be worthwhile posting this there as well http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: did you try ps to get the list of all processes? if you want to do some  grep / awk magic you can get the id of the process. pipe that to xargs and kill. Just a thought

Comment: Used ps -ef. There were no name of the dispater on it.

Comment: I used jobs, jobs -l, jobs -r and jobs -s. Nothing showed.

Comment: how are you starting the dispatcher? dispacher.sh &?

Comment: Actually it's dispacher.sh > log 2>&1 &

Comment: what distro are you on?

Answer (score 0):

create test.sh with content

```
sleep 60
```

then

```
jobs -l | grep 'test.sh &' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

this gives me the process id on Ubuntu and OSX

you can assign it to a variable and then kill it

```
pid=`jobs -l | grep 'test.sh &' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 $pid
```